# Matplotlib bar chart error: "the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. use a.any() or a.all()"

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm making a bar chart in matplotlib, and getting an error as follows:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

My code is like this:

```
N = 5
set_A = (Table1['A'], Table1['B'],
        Table1['C'], Table1['D'],
        Table1['E'])
ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.35
plt.subplot(111)
rects1 = plt.bar(ind, set_A, width, color='g')
set_B = (Table2['A'], Table2['B'],
         Table2['C'], Table2['D'],
         Table2['E'])
rects2 = plt.bar(ind+width, set_B, width, color='b')
```

The line the error refers to is

> rects1 = plt.bar(ind, set_A, width, color='g')

I don't really understand what's wrong. The code is pretty much taken straight from the example at http://matplotlib.org/users/screenshots.html

Comment: What does your `Table1` consist of?

Comment: it's just a pandas DataFrame with one row of values. A,B,C,D,E are column names

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your error. Can you print out your `set_A` and share the value you get?

Comment: My mistake. Table1 actually had a "total" row too. Thus leading to the error. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Table1 was of the wrong form: it had 2 rows, instead of the 1 I had assumed. Thus "Table1['A']" was 2 elements, rather than 1.